Can IntelliJ infer @NotNull annotations
Can IntelliJ inspections assume that every parameter or instance variable is @Nonnull without actually adding it?
I know in IntelliJ (Java | Probable bugs | Nullability and data flow problems) there is an option that says Treat non-annotated members and parameters as @Nullable.
What I am looking for is the inverse. I want every member to be @Nonnull and I will add then @Nullable to those ones that are nullable.
I have IntellJ setup with these 2 inspections:


And configured to use the jakarta annotations.
I would like the following to happen

Is this even possible in Intellij wihtout using checkerframework, error prone of a 3rd party libary? (I am also not using spring but quarkus)

Can you annotate the class with @NonNull?  I'm not familiar with the Jakarta classes and I don't use IntelliJ so I don't know if it will work the same as Spring's @NonNullFields (https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/lang/NonNullFields.html).

@Paul jakarta.annotation.Nonnull can only be applied to methods, fields and params. I forgot to add that I am not using Spring but Quarkus.
